# How do I debug an Istio envoy connectivity issue?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I have just setup a GKE (Google Cloud) based Istio Kubernetes cluster and have having some connectivity issues within the cluster.

On hitting the external ip from the outside world I get a 503 Service Unavailable from the gateway

```
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< date: Fri, 24 Jan 2020 16:17:27 GMT
< server: istio-envoy
< content-length: 0
```

Notably it's definitely hitting the cluster. I don't however know where to look next on why the service is showing unavailable.

`istioctl proxy-status` gives this which could be pertinent:

```
istio-ingressgateway-5599b67bcb-5ztp6.istio-system     SYNCED     STALE (Never Acknowledged)     SYNCED     SYNCED     istio-pilot-69c7dc4578-mtm8m     1.1.3*
```

Comment: logs from ingress gateway pod and istio proxy container running along with your pod

Comment: I get lots of this in the gateway... ```2020-01-24T15:32:37.124384Z info Envoy proxy is NOT ready: failed retrieving Envoy stats: Get http://127.0.0.1:15000/stats?usedonly: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
2020-01-24T15:32:37.898271Z info Envoy proxy is ready```

Comment: The proxy is just spamming this in to the logs ```[2020-01-24 14:29:09.537][12][warning][misc] [external/envoy/source/common/protobuf/utility.cc:174] Using deprecated option 'envoy.api.v2.Listener.use_original_dst' from file lds.proto. This configuration will be removed from Envoy soon. Please see https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/deprecated for details.```

Comment: both logs are info and warning..I am surprised there is no error log

Comment: Yeah my thoughts exactly. The interesting thing is that I get ZERO logging even when hitting the cluster (I'd expect something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my livenessProbe and readynessProbe have a conflict Istio's checks. I noticed an envoy error which stopped the proxy running because the management port was the same as the service port. Again this is new to me but it looks like I'd probably need to specify a extra port for liveness/readyness in Kubernetes land so that Istio doesn't complain.

https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/c992106720b19a93ffbf3641913885fddd9c82e3/pilot/proxy/envoy/config.go#L1020

I disabled my helm/kube liveness/readyness checks and everything burst into life.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share with us your deploy, in order to check if you are having issues with Sidecars, or if the issue is related with your replicas.